# Chamar um serviço .py dentro de outro .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-service

Boa tarde galera!

Pesquisei muito na internet e não obtive sucesso, estou com o seguinte problema para resolver:

- Possuo 3 serviços feitos em Python instalados no Windows(exemplo1.py / exemplo2.py / exemplo3.py) rodando normalmente, porém, o serviço coleta informação apenas uma vez ao mês, porém roda a cada 24hrs, em um dia especifico, o 2 e 3 são diários e rodam a cada 3 horas.
- Quero criar um outro serviço que monitore os 3 criados, que start na data exata ou uma vez ao dia e após conclusão da rotina feche por completo, startando somente no dia seguinte ou em uma data especifica.

Os meus 3 serviços se iniciam da seguinte forma:

```py
class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'exemplo1'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'exemplo1'    

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)        
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED, (self._svc_name_, ''))        
        self.main()


    def main(self):

        def retorna_data_00(dt):
            midnight = datetime.time(0)
            return datetime.datetime.combine(dt.date(), midnight)

        def data_modificacao(FileName):
            t = os.path.getmtime(FileName)
            return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(t)
```

E se encerra da seguinte forma:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

Entre essas funções esta todo o script que coleta informações do banco, transforma em planilha e envia por e-mail.

Comment: Quando voce diz que quer um serviço que monitore os outros, imagino que seja algo que mostre se todos estão rodando e que possa apontar uma possivel falha correto?

Comment: Na verdade também, preciso que que a rotina faça os pontos mencionados acima e realize o start nos serviços para e stop quando concluído.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma, exportando meu outro script como .py e chamando-o como biblioteca dentro do script atual, exemplo:

```py
try:
   import scriptantigo
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Desta forma funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Bom sendo assim temos duas observações, uma de que um serviço windows não chama outro serviço, o serviço windows esta, dês de que não ocorram problemas, sempre rodando.

Dado isso, algumas coisas teriam que ser alteradas na estrutura, por exemplo criando apenas um serviço que chama os outros `.py` que seriam arquivos independentes, para uma abordagem como essa, ou similar vc pode usar o [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Porém a abordagem que eu indico é não usar serviços windows, ao invés disto usar uma solução com containers docker com um orquestrador, essa seria a abordagem mais próxima do que vc esta desejando, e o orquestrador faria a parte de monitoramento e demais tarefas do tipo. Caso escolha partir para esta direção [esta](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) documentação ajudará bastante

Uma terceira abordagem ainda é fazer a comunicação destes serviços através de um banco de dados, porém, não recomendo.